# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.RichPopup in ADF 12c

Tags: shared-libraries, web-deployment, classnotfoundexception, oracle-adf, weblogic12c

We have a pillar design for our Huge ADF application developed by jdeveloper 12.2.1.1.0. simply we separated our business into many workspaces as following:

- SharedUI.jar: contains skin, templates, declarative components, js and so on
- SharedCode.jar: contains core classes and framework extension classes
- xxxxxFinance.ear: one of our workspaces (has SharedUI.jar and SharedCode.jar 
  in attached libraries of view layer project)

**Deployment way:**
we deploy our shared jars (SharedUI.jar and SharedCode.jar) on weblogic and also exclude them from xxxxxFinance.ear through uncheck from war/filters in WEB-INF regarding view layer war and put the names of jars in weblogic-application.xml file, at this point everything is okay and working fine.

**the issue:**
we received **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.RichPopup** at every single page
 and after my investigation I found that SharedUI project has a popup inside the root jsf page template to process change password functionality which has a binding in templateMgr class which exists in sharedCode.jar, this reasonable for handle templates activities.

**We tried to:**

1. Put Adf-richclient-api-11.jar as attached libraries in both
   SharedUI.jar and SharedCode.jar.
2. ensure that component ids are unique in all jsf page templates to avoid the ambiguity against normal jsf pages on our others projects.

but did not work also.

Finally when we hashed the biding of that popup in the template. then every thing working fine back again!!.

**Also** 
we extend ViewHandler class to be customViewHandler to control our locale and so on. I encoutered another issue regarding AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback() line. **oracle/adf/view/rich/context/AdfFacesContext
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/adf/view/rich/context/AdfFacesContext**

These exceptions shows only in deployment phase (when separate our shared jar from our main worksapces and deploy them in weblogic and prepare the war WEB-INF filters and weblogic-application.xml). I mean when every project has these two shared jars as attached libraries in development mode every thing work fine with the developer.

**If we have misunderstanding. I am wondering if there is something missing or wrong in our attachment or deployment  approach.**

- **RichPopup exceptions stack**

  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/adf/view/rich/component/rich/RichPopup
      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
      at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
      at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
      at oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.AnnotationUtils.findAnnotatedMethods(AnnotationUtils.java:211)
      at oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.AnnotationUtils.runPostConstructIfSpecified(AnnotationUtils.java:76)
      at oracle.adfinternal.controller.beans.ManagedBeanFactory.instantiateBean(ManagedBeanFactory.java:906)
      at oracle.adfinternal.controller.application.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:147)
      at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
      at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
      at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
      at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:150)
      at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:199)
      at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
      at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponentApplyAnnotations(ApplicationImpl.java:1943)
      at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:1149)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.createComponent(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:596)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:175)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.FacetHandler.apply(FacetHandler.java:104)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.FacetHandler.apply(FacetHandler.java:104)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.IncludeDefHandler.apply(IncludeDefHandler.java:69)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.IncludeHandler.applyNextHandler(IncludeHandler.java:95)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.FacetHandler.apply(FacetHandler.java:104)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.IncludeDefHandler.apply(IncludeDefHandler.java:69)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.IncludeHandler.applyNextHandler(IncludeHandler.java:95)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.facelets.rich.RichDocumentHandler.applyNextHandler(RichDocumentHandler.java:68)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:202)
      at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:225)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
      at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1006)
      at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.buildView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:94)
      at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.view.ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.buildView(ViewDeclarationLanguageWrapper.java:94)
      at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.application.ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl$ChangeApplyingVDLWrapper.buildView(ViewDeclarationLanguageFactoryImpl.java:322)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.ResponseRenderManager._processViewDefinitionLanguage(ResponseRenderManager.java:105)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.ResponseRenderManager.runRenderView(ResponseRenderManager.java:41)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1264)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeRenderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1107)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:348)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:258)
      at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
      at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
      at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
      at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
      at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
      at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
      at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
      at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
      at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
      at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
      at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
      at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
      at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
      at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
      at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
      at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
      at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
      at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
      at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
      at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
      at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1686)
      at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1646)
      at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
      at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
      at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
      at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
      at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
      at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
      at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
      at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.adf.view.rich.component.rich.RichPopup
      at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1025)
      at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:986)
      at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:607)
      at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:539)
      at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:492)
      at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:469)
      ... 131 more

  **- AdfFacesContext exceptions stack:**

  oracle/adf/view/rich/context/AdfFacesContext
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/adf/view/rich/context/AdfFacesContext
          at com.ntg.erp.core.view.ErpViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ErpViewHandlerWrapper.java:73)
          at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.ResponseRenderManager.runRenderView(ResponseRenderManager.java:52)
          at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._renderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1264)
          at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executeRenderResponse(LifecycleImpl.java:1107)
          at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl._executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:348)
          at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:258)
          at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
          at oracle.adf.model.servlet.ADFBindingFilter.doFilter(ADFBindingFilter.java:207)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
          at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.RegistrationFilter.doFilter(RegistrationFilter.java:105)
          at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
          at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.activedata.AdsFilter.doFilter(AdsFilter.java:60)
          at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl$FilterListChain.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:529)
          at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:354)
          at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:232)
          at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:92)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
          at com.ntg.erp.admin.view.servlets.AdminFilter.doFilter(AdminFilter.java:58)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
          at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
          at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:141)
          at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
          at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
          at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:650)
          at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:124)
          at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:232)
          at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:94)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
          at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:248)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
          at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
          at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
          at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
          at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1686)
          at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1646)
          at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
          at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
          at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
          at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
          at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
          at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
          at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
          at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)

Comment: How do you use components from SharedUI.jar in xxxFinance.ear?

Comment: we use page templates which has a popup with binding

Answer (score 0):

All issues resolved. that was because some developers did some mistakes regarding path classes and libraries attachment.